# Java Specific webclient connect timeout per request

Tags: java, spring-boot, timeout, spring-webflux, webclient

I have to call different urls with different connection timeout with webclient. But i found that we can set connect timeout globally only and not per resquest .. what to do please to set this timeout on a request without creating a new weblient each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate one webclient per url. For each webclient, you can set the connection timeout :

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
  .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000);
WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
  .baseUrl("http://yourendpoint:8080")
  .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
  .build();
```

Then reuse this webclient for all the calls to the configured url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the  probleme is i have many different urls that i receive from another service and they change everytime and they have their own connection timeout and request timeout, so if i receive like 100 urls i need to create the webclient 100 times ? there is no other way ?

Comment: ok. I didn't understand this from the question. I would have suggested a cache based on the timeout values (without specifying the baseURL in the webClient builder), but if connection and request timeouts aren't linked together, it can be a bit complex. Then yes, I'm afraid that you'll have to create a webclient per URL, and cache them using the URL as cache key (hoping that you will not receive the same url with different timeouts)